# Boundedness of sequence

Tags: complex-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider a dynamical systems over complex numbers $$ z_{n+1}=\frac{\alpha}{z_{n}}+ \frac{\beta}{z_{n-1}},\qquad n=0,1,\ldots $$

where the parameters $\alpha, ~\beta$ are complex numbers, and the initial conditions $%
z_{-1}$ and $z_{0}$ are arbitrary complex numbers.

For any initial values $z_{-1}$ and $z_{0}$, does the sequence  $\{z_n\}$ bounded for all $n$? If so, what is the proof?

Does this sequence $\{z_n\}$ converge always? If so, how that be ensured?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but a couple of ideas: you have 2 fixed points, $\sqrt{\alpha \beta}$ and $-\sqrt{\alpha \beta}$. The behaviour you can expect are: convergence towards one of them, oscillation between them, divergence... those will come from studying $|z_n - \sqrt{\alpha \beta}|$ and $|z_n|$, which is not trivial.

Comment: The fixed points are $\pm \sqrt{\alpha+\beta}$

Comment: You're right, typo on my side.